# Run reducer after state is updated by another reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Let's say I've got an app with two reducers - `tables` and `footer` combined using `combineReducers()`.

When I click on some button two actions are being dispatched - one after another: `"REFRESH_TABLES"` and `"REFRESH_FOOTER"`.

`tables` reducer is listening for the first action and it modifies the state of tables. The second action triggers `footer` reducer. **The thing is it needs current state of tables in order to do it's thing**.

My implementation looks something like below.

Button component:

```jsx
import React from 'react';

const refreshButton = React.createClass({
    refresh () {
        this.props.refreshTables();
        this.props.refreshFooter(this.props.tables);
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.refresh}>Refresh</button>
        )
    }
});

export default refreshButton;
```

ActionCreators:

```jsx
export function refreshTables() {
    return {
        type: REFRESH_TABLES
    }
}

export function refreshFooter(tables) {
    return {
        type: REFRESH_FOOTER,
        tables
    }
}
```

The problem is that the props didn't update at this point so the state of tables that `footer` reducer gets is also not updated yet and it contains the data form before the `tables` reducer run.

So **how do I get a fresh state to the reducer when multiple actions are dispatched one after another** from the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although splitting it asynchronous may help, the issue may be in the fact that you are using `combineReducers`. You should not have to rely on the tables from props, you want to use the source of truth which is state.

You need to look at rewriting the root reducer so you have access to all of state. I have done so by writing it like this.

`const rootReducer = (state, action) => ({
  tables: tableReducer(state.tables, action, state),
  footer: footerReducer(state.footer, action, state)
});`

With that you now have access to full state in both reducers so you shouldn't have to pass it around from props.

Your reducer could then looks like this.

`const footerReducer = (state, action, { tables }) => {
...
};`

That way you are not actually pulling in all parts of state as it starts to grow and only access what you need.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Seems you need to handle the *actions* `async` so you can use a custom *middleware* like [redux-thuk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) to do something like this:

#### actions.js

```
function refreshTables() {
  return {
    type: REFRESH_TABLES
  }
}

function refreshFooter(tables) {
  return {
    type: REFRESH_FOOTER,
    tables
  }
}

export function refresh() {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch(refreshTables())
      .then(() => dispatch(refreshFooter(getState().tables)))
  }
}
```

#### component

```
const refreshButton = React.createClass({
  refresh () {
    this.props.refresh();
  },
  {/* ... */}
});
```

Comment: Thx for the reply! <<Rest of comment deleted>>